# FOC current and speed limits

Tags: simulation, brushless-dc-motor, motor-controller

I am trying to simulate BLDC drive using FOC with svPWM. The drive works very well in the continous operating regions, however i also want to include current and speed limits on the simulation. I have the datasheet of the motor stating the peak current and max speed of the motor, but how can i implement these limits in the drive model?

Comment: It's not clear what are you asking. Would you like that computer while doing simulation smokes, or reboots, or you can throw it trough the window or what?

Comment: Much more information needed. What simulator (links). What access do you have to simulation parameters? -  Full current control should be part of a FOC system. Also providing data sheet links to the motor and anything else used may be useful.

Comment: I am sorry the question was not clear, i will try to explain in different manner. I have built a simulation model in openModelica that has a BLDC motor model and a svPWM drive model. Everything works fine as i said, but i want to know how a normal drive regulates the peak current and speed limit in the FOC scheme so that i can apply the same approach in my model.

Comment: Ummm, what does FOC mean? Can you [edit] the question to make it clear?

Answer (score 0):

The peak current and maximum speed of the motor are related to failure modes. The motor manufacturer knows what effects are avoided by setting limits on the speed and current, but all the use normally needs to know is the limits. If you were to ask the manufacturer, they may or may not reveal that information.

The motor's rotor will have been dynamically balanced at some speed to some vibration limit. Operating above that limit is likely to shorten the life of the bearings. Just considering normal wear mechanisms, bearing life will be shortened with operation at high speeds even if the balance is good.

Centrifugal force on the rotor could cause it to fail. Depending on the construction, magnets could become dislodged due to centrifugal force or vibration.

The thermal effects of current would be related to RMS current rather than peak current. However, there may be a risk of demagnetization at some level of peak current.

A great deal of detailed information about the motor design would be required to simulate the effects of exceeding the peak current and maximum speed ratings. With the proper information, you could probably simulate motor, but that would not make much sense as part of a controller simulation.